# Vundle doesn't load plugin

Tags: vim, themes, vundle

This is my `.vimrc` located under `$HOME/.vimrc`. I've installed Vundle.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'dracula/dracula-theme'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

I'm able to execute `:PluginInstall` successfully installing `dracula-theme`. Unfortunately the theme is not applied and the style remains unchanged? Any clues?

Comment: Add to `.vimrc`: `syntax on` and `colorscheme dracula`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Plugin 'dracula/dracula-theme'` to your vimrc and using `:PluginInstall`  make the colorscheme available to Vim but it doesn't say to Vim to use it.

As @dNitro said in the comment you have to use the command `colorscheme` to set the desired colorscheme. Thus you need to add a line `colorscheme dracula` to your vimrc *after* the line `" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line`.